# jQuery Mobile List View: initialize error

Tags: jquery, html, listview, jquery-mobile

I assume this has a simple solution.

I have a list that I want to make into a listview. Stuff is added to it dynamically.

HTML:

```
<div data-role="content" data-theme="b" class="content-primary">
    <div id="friends_list_view" class="content-primary" data-theme="c"> 
        <ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-theme="c">
        </ul>
    </div>  
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
for(i in names){
      listString =  '<li><a href="#">'+i+'</a></li>';
      $("#friends_list_view ul").append(listString);
}

$("#friends_list_view ul").listview('refresh');
$.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
$.mobile.changePage( "#friends", { transition: "slide"} );
```

I get:

> Uncaught cannot call methods on listview prior to initialization;
>   attempted to call method 'refresh'

When I change it to just `$("#friends_list_view ul").listview();` I get:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'jQuery16409763167318888009'
>   of undefined

Comment: try without the ul: $("#friends_list_view").listview();

Comment: @Phill Do dice :( The weird thing is that it works with that exact code but different ids on another page...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQM PageInit() Docs:

- http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html

> **pageinit**
>  Triggered on the page being initialized, after initialization occurs. We recommend binding to this event instead of
>   DOM ready() because this will work regardless of whether the page is
>   loaded directly or if the content is pulled into another page as part
>   of the Ajax navigation system.

Try this:

- http://jsfiddle.net/GVCHF/

JS

```
$( '#home' ).live( 'pageinit',function(event){
    var names = ['Bob','Bill','Phill','Will'];
    var listString = '';
    for(i in names) {
          listString +=  '<li><a href="#">'+i+'</a></li>';
    }
    $("#friends_list_view ul").append(listString);

    $("#friends_list_view ul").listview('refresh');
    $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
    $.mobile.changePage( "#friends", { transition: "slide"} );
});
```

HTML

```
<div data-role="page" id="home">
    <div data-role="content" data-theme="b" class="content-primary">
        <div id="friends_list_view" class="content-primary" data-theme="c"> 
            <ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-theme="c">
            </ul>
        </div>  
    </div>
</div>​
```

Answer (score 6):

The page with the listview possibly isn't initialized. Try to call this first:

```
$('#pageWithListview').page();
```